# Is it possible to label an arbitrary point on a graph?

Tags: dygraphs

I think the answer is no to this question, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking some workaround.

I am using `underlayCallback` to highlight several regions in a series, but there is no way to label the highlighted areas as far as I can tell. I would like to just add a div at a fixed x,y location on the graph. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

I also looked at hairlines, but I would rather use the highlight feature.
I can add a div on the graph outside the chart, but it does not move with the data as it changes or zooms.  Right now I just have a legend on the side of the chart that explains the highlights, but is not the look I am going for.

Any other ideas out there?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of using an external `<div>` is reasonable. The only trick is that you'll have to reposition it every time that your `underlayCallback` is called. dygraphs itself does something similar for axis labels and annotations.

The [`toDomCoords`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#toDomCoords) method will help you convert x, y data values into DOM coordinates for absolutely positioning a `<div>`.